# Can I convince PyCharm to watch project files on an EncFS mount?

Tags: filesystems, pycharm, ubuntu-13.10

I recently started using EncFS to secure my employer's code (in the event that my laptop is stolen). However, when I start PyCharm I now get the following warning (every time):

> **External file changes sync may be slow**
>   Project files cannot be watched (are they under network mount?)

The files are on a local mount. I imagine there is some overhead introduced by EncFS, but I would hope it is negligible. How can I convince PyCharm to stop worrying about it and treat them as local files?

(As a last resort, how can I stop this warning every time I start?)

Comment: I get this error and I am not using EndFS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an old post, but still:

According to the [JetBrains Bug Tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-102091) and the [Canonical Bug Tracker](https://bugs.launchpad.net/intellij-idea/+bug/1176893) you need to make `<pyCharm>/bin/fsnotifier64` executable.